# toupper and tolower function in linux using XOR bitwise operation

Tags: c, linux, string, gcc

In [Linux Source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/ctype.h) code

The implementation of tolower and topupper is implemented as below

```
static inline unsigned char __tolower(unsigned char c)
{
        if (isupper(c))
            c -= 'A'-'a';
        return c;
}


 static inline unsigned char __toupper(unsigned char c)
 {
    if (islower(c))
            c -= 'a'-'A';
    return c;
 }
```

Can i use XOR (^) Bitwise operation as show below .

Is there any potential Bug if i use xor operation?

```
 c -= 'A'-'a'; ----> c = c ^ 0x20 ;  //using xor to convert to lower case to upper case and vice versa
```

Comment: And that would be faster, because ...?

Comment: Why do you think this would be faster?

Comment: `c -= 'A'-'a';` instead of `c += 'a'-'A'`... only in Linux... (Why not make things not complicated when you can not make things not easy?)

Comment: The OP is referring to functions used in the Linux kernel, which explicitly support only the ISO 8859-1 character set (with the current [`_ctype[]`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/lib/ctype.c) array contents). Because the Linux kernel runs in a freestanding C environment, and very much relies on known compiler behaviour (rather than C or POSIX standards), it should not be used as a guide for normal, userspace application programming in C.

Comment: @NominalAnimal so for  userspace application programming in C i cannot use this function as reference ? what might be possible bugs incurs??

Comment: I don't see any problem as long as we stay in the ISO 8859-1 character set. But maybe XOR is slighly slower ?

Comment: @vinayhunachyal In general, you're not supposed to assume things about your character set encoding. That's why there is a `tolower()` function *in the standard library*, so you don't need to implement it for each platform. The Linux kernel, of course, kind of *is* a platform so that argument doesn't apply.

Comment: In any case, that `0x20` is still better written as `'a' - 'A'` in my opinion, in the Linux case that is (where we can make assumptions about the character sets in use).

Comment: @vinayhunachyal: I didn't say 'cannot', I said 'should not'. Other than restricting to ASCII-compatible sets (with `x - ('A' - 'a')`) or ASCII- or EBCDIC-compatible sets (with `x ^ ' '`), I don't see how *bugs* would crop up. My worry is that you don't seem to understand that this code will never be a bottleneck, a speed limiting factor, so there is no reason to try to "optimize" this. All scenarios that I can think of where optimizing this would matter, have other, algorithm-level optimizations, that yield much better speedups!

Answer (score 4):

You very probably can, but it's very hard to see the point.

XOR:ing a byte value with a constant isn't faster than adding (or subtracting) a constant. And the benefit that it becomes a toggle (i.e. `toupper()` and `tolower()` can be the same code) is very small since the amount of code is so small.

When disassembled, these two functions:

```
int my_tolower1(int c)
{
  return c + 'a' - 'A';
}

int my_tolower2(int c)
{
  return c ^ ('a' - 'A');
}
```

Pretty much compile to the same thing, modulo of course the add vs xor:

```
my_tolower1(int):
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        addl    $32, %eax
        popq    %rbp
        ret
my_tolower2(int):
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        xorl    $32, %eax
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

Both the `addl` and `xorl` instructions are three bytes, so there's no difference there. I assume they're both single-cycle on most interesting CPUs these days.

Note, as I said in my comment, that in general you shouldn't go around and assume your C program runs in an environment where you can make these kinds of assumptions. The Linux kernel, however, is such an environment.

Comment: thank you unwind this sounds better explanation for faster implementation case...

Comment: One minor difference: On some platforms, addition/subtraction changes processor flags (like carry or overflow) that bitwise operations don't, so the compiler has more leeway to reorder the latter.

Comment: @nwellnhof That might matter in a larger context, but here we just do the operation on a single character then leave the function so I don't think there's much opportunity. And, of course, the compiler might switch the add to an xor anyway if it can prove it's the right thing to do ...

Comment: I agree that it's unlikely to see a difference, but the code in the question uses inline functions, so it might actually matter in a larger context

Answer (score 2):

On ASCII platforms, `'a' - 'A'` equals `0x20`, letters A-Z and a-z have consecutive values, and all letters only differ in the six least significant bits, so you can use `c = c ^ 0x20`. But the C standard doesn't specify the character encoding, making this approach unportable.

A slightly more portable and self-documenting variant is:

```
c ^= 'A' ^ 'a';
```

(The C standard also doesn't mandate that letters A-Z and a-z have consecutive values, so the Linux kernel code isn't strictly portable as well. But it makes fewer assumptions than the XOR trick.)

Answer (score 0):

It would be more correctly to use the space character ' ' instead of the magic number 0x20. In this case the functions will be also valid for the EBCDIC table.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

char tolower(char c)
{
    return c ^ ' ';
}

char toupper(char c)
{
    return c ^ ' ';
}

int main( void )
{
    char s[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    puts( s );

    for (char *p = s; *p; ++p) *p = tolower(*p);

    puts( s );

    for (char *p = s; *p; ++p) *p = toupper(*p);

    puts( s );
}
```

The program output is

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Of course before calling the functions you should check whether the argument is an alpha character in the given range.

Comment: @YassineHoussni I created nothing. I just showed how the functions in the question can be implemented using the ^ operator.

Comment: space is nothing but ASCII value of space  0x20

Comment: @vinayhunachyal I think I pointed out why it is better to use the space character did not I?

Comment: yes i agree but my query is that is there any bug if i use xor ?

Comment: @vinayhunachyal See the program output.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow But `0x20` isn't "_the space character_", it's the "_bits that need to be flipped_" to move to/from upper-/lowercase ASCII characters. That this _happens_ to be the same as the character-value of a space is essentially an accident of the ASCII table.

Comment: @TripeHound You are right. But what to do with the function if the EBCDIC is used? Do you suggest to rewrite the function that to use new "bits"?:)